# NUnit how can I prevent code repetition

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I'm trying to work on Unit Test best practices, and I've come across a problem that I can't get my head around. The production code has a function that transforms a given object into another, like so:

Original Object:

```
public OriginalObject
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public string Value {get; set;}
    public int FormCode {get; set;}
    public int NameCode {get; set;}
    //other properties
}

public TransformedObject
{
    public string Value {get; set;}
    public int FormCode {get; set;}
    //other properties
}
```

Transform function:

```
public TransformedObject Transform(OriginalObject originalObject)
{
    var TransformedObject = new TransformedObject();
    TransformedObject.Value = originalObject.Value;
    TransformedObject.FormCode = originalObject.FormCode;
    return TransformedObject;
}
```

And the test looks like this:

```
[Test]
public void Transform_NonNullOptionObject_ValuePropertyIsTheSame()
{
    OptionObjectTransform transform = InitTransform();
    CustomOptionObject result = transform.Transform(optionObject);//mock optionObject
    Assert.AreEqual(optionObject.Value, result.Value);
}
```

So my question is do I have to write a test for each property? or is there a way to use the `[TestCase]` to pass in the property I want to test? or should the test check to see if all properties are equal? 
I don't think the last one is the solution since if the test fails then we wouldn't know what property doesn't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A limitation of NUnit (and all other xUnit frameworks) is that they fail on the first assert failure and do not run the other asserts. As you say, this means that if one tries to test many values, through many asserts, there's no way to detect multiple failures.

However, as you also identify, many repeated tests, each of which tests a different value isn't ideal either as it involves lots of duplicated code, just to work around a limitation of NUnit.

The "best of both worlds" solution is to test arrays of objects for equality. This could take the form of:

```
[Test]
public void Transform_NonNullOptionObject_ValuePropertyIsTheSame()
{
    OptionObjectTransform transform = InitTransform();
    CustomOptionObject result = transform.Transform(optionObject);
    var expected = new[] { optionObject.Value, optionObject.FormCode };
    var actual = new[] { result.Value, result.FormCode };
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

That way, you test many values with one test and can know about many failures simultaneously.

Comment: When going through the tests if this test fails, then there wouldn't really be a way to know exactly which property failed, we just know that one of them did, correct?

Comment: The comparison might report something like: Expected { "a", 1 }, but got { "b", 2 }. Therefore you can see every property that didn't meatch, not just the first one.

Answer (score 0):

For simple mapping (i.e. where there are few calculated mappings, or "if"s) I use [SharpTestEx](https://sharptestex.codeplex.com/), where there is a [nice `Satisfy` assertion](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/12/sharptestsex-100beta-satisfy-your-test.html), which reports all wrong assertions.

The code goes like this:

```
mapped.Satisfy( m =>
    m.Prop1 == source.SomeData + "zz" &&
    m.Prop2 == source.Prop2 ...
);
```